# Campaign Member Status tallies

Tags: reporting, campaign

Hi I am trying to track attendance of our participants over many events (campaigns). I have created custom campaign members statuses. 
From what I understand, statuses that are marked as "responded" are counted as 1, and statuses that are not are counted as 0.

I then created a report to see attendance across all events (campaigns). 
I want it to count the responded statuses but not the other statuses. 
It is counting both.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a field filter where the field "responded" equals 1? That should eliminate all other answers, if I understand your question correctly.